# Get Post number(digits) In a String

Tags: python, string

How to find the digit(post number) after @ and before ;; since there are other digits in the string. Finally, it produced [507, 19, 1].

Example:

```
   post507 = "@507::empty in Q1/Q2::can list be empty::yes"
   post19 = "@19::Allowable functions::empty?, first, rest::"
   post1 = "@1::CS116 W2015::Welcome to first post::Thanks!"
   cs116 =   [post507, post1, post19]


   print (search_piazza(cs116, "l")) =>[507,1,19]
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=@)\d+
```

use a `lookbehind`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/33#python

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=@)\d+', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "\"@507empty in Q1/Q2can list be emptyyes\"\n \"@19Allowable functionsempty?, first, rest\"\n \"@1CS116 W2015Welcome to first postThanks!"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

iF input is in `list`

use

```
x=["@507;;empty in Q1/Q2;;can list be empty;;yes",
"@19;;Allowable functions;;empty?, first, rest;;",
"@1;;CS116 W2015;;Welcome to first post;;Thanks!"]
print [re.findall(r"(?<=@)\d+",k) for k in x]
```

Comment: can you do that without import re?

Comment: @YeYang without re you will have to use `find`,`split` etc.wont be a cleaner code

Comment: I tried with split, using str.split to separate them

Comment: @YeYang how did you try it.what was your `test_str`

Comment: (list (map (lambda x: str.split(x) fn-name)))

Comment: [['@507::empty', 'in', 'Q1/Q2::can', 'list', 'be', 'empty::yes'], ['@1::CS116', 'W2015::Welcome', 'to', 'first', 'post::Thanks!'], ['@19::Allowable', 'functions::empty?,', 'first,', 'rest::']]

Comment: after that I am not sure to get the number

Comment: @YeYang what's your exact input. Input in your question and the input in the above comment are different.

Comment: def search_piazza(posts, keyword):
    return  (list (map (lambda y: str.split(y), (list  (filter (lambda x: keyword in x, posts))))))

Comment: you still using the re import

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the digit(post number) in string after `@` and before `;;`

Use `re.findall` along with the list_comprehension.

```
>>> l = ["@507;;empty in Q1/Q2;;can list be empty;;yes",
    "@19;;Allowable functions;;empty?, first, rest;;",
    "@1;;CS116 W2015;;Welcome to first post;;Thanks!"]
>>> [j for i in l for j in re.findall(r'@(\d+);;', i)]
['507', '19', '1']
```

Finally convert the resultant number to integer.

```
>>> [int(j) for i in l for j in re.findall(r'@(\d+);;', i)]
[507, 19, 1]
```

**Without regex.**

```
>>> l = ["@507;;empty in Q1/Q2;;can list be empty;;yes",
    "@19;;Allowable functions;;empty?, first, rest;;",
    "@1;;CS116 W2015;;Welcome to first post;;Thanks!"]
>>> for i in l:
        for j in i.split(';;'):
            for k in j.split('@'):
                if k.isdigit():
                    print(k)


507
19
1
```

List_comprehension:

```
>>> [int(k) for i in l for j in i.split(';;') for k in j.split('@') if k.isdigit()]
[507, 19, 1]
```

Comment: can you do that without import re? Like using some str function

Comment: i am a beginner in python, waht are i and j represent for?

Comment: easy code? i think there is no other easy code than the second method.

Comment: iterate over each element in the list l and each element was assigned to the variable i for each iteration. Likewise, j represent each element in the list produced on splitting the `i` according to `;;`.